# How to make classLoader loadClass() direction.(except cache)

Tags: java, caching, load, classloader

class loader's find class process is like under. 
find cached one : child first

and if not exist then,

load class : parent first.

---

I want to find cached class from child classLoader to parent classloader. 
Also loadClass direction is child to parent.

my hope

find cached one : child first

and if not exist then,

load class : child first

---

Is there any good way?

Under is example situation.

---

There are two classLoader.

ClassLoader A has a class Same.class which is in Version1.jar

And ClassLoader B has a class Same.class which is in Version2.jar

ClassLoader A is a parent of ClassLoader B.

When Same.class(in Version1.jar) is loaded on classLoader A and then passed to classLoader B.

classLoader B find class Same.class. The process is 
First find cached one from child to parent.
And then load class from parent to child.

So, Same.class is found on classLoader A because, it was cached classLoader A.
There is no problem.

my problem is below.
At first Same.class is not loaded from classLoader A.
and classLoader B request to load Same.class.
At this point Same.class is loaded classLoader A because, Same.class is not cached before and load class is parent first. I want classLoader B load Same.class which is in Version2.jar.

Comment: Is class loader B a URL class loader?

Comment: @IndraBasak Yes!